# React Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using react with bootstrap (not react-bootstrap) and working on the navbar.

The navbar at a certain width (<768px) becomes a mobile navbar with links in a collapsed view as you probably already know.

Is there a way to find out if it's in mobile view? I have a search button that I want the onclick event to be different in each views.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ctrl-Shift-I then Ctrl-Shift-M in chrome to open developer tools and emulate a mobile device, then you can mess around and see it change when it goes into mobile mode.

You can also inspect the navbar element and when it goes into mobile the dev tools should blink showing it has new classes and css applied to it.